# 502 bad gateway when adding a new simple product to a configurable product at a later stage

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product, simple-product

i'm using magento 1.7.2 I have configurable products with simple products (not individual visible). If a product is some time in the database and new other configurable products (with simple) have been added to magento and there has to be added a new extra simple product to a older configurable product this result in a 502 bad gateway in the front site for that specific product. Is this a issue with magento or is there something else going on and if so can it be solved other then deleting the whole product and import or create it again with the extra simple product.

Comment: this is something wrong with php, try to disable opcode cache